# PHP: building query from array foreach

Tags: php

```
$test=$_POST['Cities'];
 foreach ($test as $t){
 $query .= " AND u.bostadsort = \'".$t."\'";
 }
```

I have this for my

```
<select size="6" name="Cities[]" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="">All</option>
    <option value="1">C1</option>
    <option value="2">C2</option>
    <option value="3">S3</option>
    <option value="4">S4</option>
    <option value="5">S5</option>
</select>
```

But its not right at all.

What I'm trying to do is when you pick the cities(in the search form), it puts all the values into an array.

Now I would like to have it write like this, if you e.g pick 2, 4, 5

```
AND u.bostadsort = '2' OR u.bostadsort = '4' OR u.bostadsort = '5'
```

(maybe you could do this easier to, but this is the only way i know, using "OR")

So if you picked more than 1 then it should be OR, instead of the AND i got.

Maybe I done it in a wrong way, and there is a better method doing this than foreach..

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

You could use `IN` instead, which lets you supply multiple values:

```
if (is_array($_POST['Cities']))
{
  // If multiple values were selected, handle them
  $cities = array();
  foreach ($_POST['Cities'] as $city)
  {
    if (!empty($city))
    {
      $cities[] = mysql_real_escape_string($city);
    }
  }
}
elseif (!empty($_POST['Cities']))
{
  // ... or was a single, non-empty value passed in?
  $cities = array(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Cities']));
}

if (count($cities))
{
  $query .= " AND u.bostadsort IN ('" . join("', '", $cities) . "')";
}
```

Note that I am passing each value through [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) before using it in the query; this is done to prevent [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). If you are not using MySQL, the other RDBMSes have similar functions.

See http://www.ideone.com/UVXuu for an example (ideone doesn't seem to have mysql enabled, so the calls to `mysql_real_escape_string` are removed).

Alternately, you could use [PDO](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)'s [`prepare`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) and [`execute`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) methods:

```
$cities = $_POST['Cities'];
if (count($cities))
{
  $query .= " AND u.bostadsort IN (?" . str_repeat(', ?', count($cities) - 1) . ")";
}

// $db is a PDO object
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute($cities);
```

(Of course, this solution ignores how you build the rest of your query because you don't give it in your question, so you'd want to parameterize the other parts as well.)

Comment: The first solution, is working great! How can I check if its empty? if(empty(join($cities)) ?

Comment: You could check `empty($cities)` (no need for the `join`) or `count($cities) == 0`

Comment: Im getting Warning: array_map() [function.array-map]: Argument #2 should be an array

Comment: tested count too, same results. Count is 1 when i pick All, that´s why it still runs the $query ... And it doesnt run the $query when I dont pick anything, but then I receive the above err.

Comment: Ok one issue is fixed, but now the last remains, if you pick All, it runs the query. (All has empty value)

Comment: Could you help me with the last issue?

Comment: @user As far as I can see my code works. Check out http://www.ideone.com/UVXuu for an example (ideone doesn't have mysql compiled in so I took the `mysql_real_escape_string` calls out and mocked up `$_POST['Cities']` as `$posted_cities`) -- when All, 1 and 2 are selected, only 1 and 2 end up in the query. Or see http://www.ideone.com/uLbTQ -- only "all" is selected, no query is built.

Comment: It still run the query, and are adding "AND u.bostadsort IN ('')". I think its because this: if (count($cities)) { , because this says if theres more than one. And if you pick "All" then it returns "1" in count($cities). But not picking anything at all works fine. Or maybe I should give "All" a value in the option e.g "none", and then check if count OR !($cities[1] == "none") something like that?

Comment: As, !empty($_POST['Cities']) will return "Array" so it wont be empty, thats why it runs it.. no?